# Is object a subclass of type in Python 2.X?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, subclass, metaclass

I read from Learning Python (5th edition) that (on Page 1364, Chapter 40):

> In Python 2.X, new-style classes inherit from **object**, which is a subclass of **type**; classic classes are instances of **type** and are not created from a class.

However,

```
issubclass(object, type)
```

gives me

```
False
```

in Python 2.7.

So, it seems that the author made a false statement that **object** is a subclass of **type**, or am I missing anything?

Comment: What if you try `issubclass(type(object), type)`?

Comment: "classic classes are instances of `type`" is false, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`object` is not a subclass of `type`, that would make it a [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/5079316). Instead `object` is an *instance* of type `type`.

The function [`issubclass`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#issubclass) checks if a given class inherits from another.

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

print(issubclass(B, A)) # True
```

It does not check if an instance os of a given type. To verify if `object` is indeed of type `type`, you want to use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#isinstance).

```
print(isinstance(object, type)) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `isinstance()`. In [python 2.7.10](https://repl.it/repls/LoudVeneratedService)

```
print object
print isinstance(object, type)
print issubclass(object, type)
print object.__class__
```

outputs

```
<type 'object'>
True
False
<type 'type'>
```

`type` is a metaclass as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/10254804)